# Kubernetes API server response timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, argo-workflows

Seeing some of our Workflow jobs are getting failed with connection timeout error. We are using Argo Workflow manager to run jobs. we are observing Argo is losing connectivity to its workflows and our inter dependent workflow schema is getting failed with the below errors. so when I checked Kubernetes API server logs I am seeing these errors. is there any way I can increase any timeout settings for Kubernetes API server non running jobs?

**Errors:**

```
status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &net.OpError{Op:"write", Net:"tcp", Source:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc095d6de90), Addr:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc095d6dec0), Err:(*os.SyscallError)(0xc0287c4d00)}
E0817 17:14:46.575773 1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &net.OpError{Op:"write", Net:"tcp", Source:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc07d555530), Addr:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc07d555560), Err:(*os.SyscallError)(0xc0be7c70e0)}
E0817 17:14:46.576855 1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &net.OpError{Op:"write", Net:"tcp", Source:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc07c5a03f0), Addr:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc07c5a0420), Err:(*os.SyscallError)(0xc07c7454e0)}
E0817 17:15:28.402137 1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &net.OpError{Op:"write", Net:"tcp", Source:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc09013ea20), Addr:(*net.TCPAddr)(0xc09013ea50), Err:(*os.SyscallError)(0xc0cd00f520)}
E0817 17:23:48.779008 1 runtime.go:78] Observed a panic: &errors.errorString{s:"killing connection/stream because serving request timed out and response had been started"} (killing connection/stream because serving request timed out and response had been started)
```

**Client Version: v1.17.2**

**Server Version: v1.17.2**

Host OS:
**Centos 7.7**

CNI:
**Weave**

Thanks,
CS

Comment: What Argo version are you running? Are there any logs in the Argo controller which may be helpful?

Comment: Did you fix this issue  ?